# Windows Service Screen Shoot?

Tags: windows, service

i kind a newbie on windows service programing, my idea is that i want to create a windows service that will take a screen shoot of the desktop client,i mean i want to attach this to a aspx page, the screen shoot code is working 100% but problem is when i trigger windows service after install it, nothing happened.

I debugged it and there was not prp, after that i made a small screenCapture.exe file to do the job and try calling it from the service, all i got was a black screen, tried everything with it and no luck.

Then i read about desktops and stuff like that, but honestly i don't understand any of that, i goggled a lot but no luck so far, problem is that i saw a website that implement this function so it can be done. BUT HOW ??? please help me out cause i am stuck here, and if u do explain good, cause as i told u i am kinda new to this

Comment: Are you trying to monitor your kids use of the computer?

Comment: did you create the service with the [`interact`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx) type flag?

Answer (score 3):

A service does not have access to the desktop. You might want to create a program that runs when the user is logged in interactively.

Comment: It is a good answer hitting the key points, but future readers might read posts like https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ to better understand Windows session isolation, which is why this answer says so.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which Windows you are using...but starting with Vista, the ability to interact with desktop from a service has been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

A service will not have access to the desktop. This is done intentionally by Microsoft for better security. The other option you can try is, goto the service properties and give it option to interact with the desktop. This can be done using local user permissions.

Comment: "interact with the desktop" is not an option for that purpose either. Sounds like you need to revisit Windows session isolation.